# In the developer console Objects

Tags: developer-console

In the developer console when you go to file open you can choose an Entity Type of Classes, Triggers, Pages, Page Components, Objects, Static Resources, and Packages. In my org there are 2 Objects listed that aren't objects in my org when I check in Salesforce, at least they don't show up when I search for them. Can someone explain what these objects are and point me to some documentation on them? The objects are Store_CommentSetting__c and Store_Comment_Setting__ChangeEvent.

Comment: Are those custom objects or Standard Object. If they are standard Objects can you edit the post and  mention the name of those.

Comment: you missed mentioning the object names.  Can you please edit the question and add which objects are you referring to.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the object names.  Have you checked Custom Metadata and Custom Settings?

Answer (score 1):

If they are custom objects(ending with __c), they are custom setting.
Custom settings are similar to custom objects.
custom setting are listed as custom object when:

1.retrieve custom object from salesforce to your vscode

2.when your are deploying them.

So try searching them in custom settings and see if you find them. Go to setup -> quick find->custom setting